# Translate both ways, print word if not in keys or values

Tags: python

I am having trouble with this one have looked up much possible solutions and can't seem to find the right one, my trouble here is I can't get the program to print the word typed in the input if the word isn't a key or value using Python 2.7

```
Tuc={"i":["o"],"love":["wau"],"you":["uo"],"me":["ye"],"my":["yem"],"mine":["yeme"],"are":["sia"]}

while True:
    #Translates English to Tuccin and visa versa

    translation = str(raw_input("Enter content for translation.\n").lower())

    #this is for translating full phrases, both ways.
    input_list = translation.split()


    for word in input_list:
        #English to Tuccin
            if word in Tuc and word not in v:
                print ("".join(Tuc[word]))

            #Tuccin to English
            for k, v in Tuc.iteritems():
                if word in v and word not in Tuc:
                    print k
```

Comment: So whats the problem with your code?

Comment: `v` is being used without being declared in the first `if`

Comment: There's a lot  more to the code so I can't have the behaviors change much, this is just the portion I'm having trouble with to better describe the issue is when I type in for example I hate you I get back o uo, I need it to respond with o hate(word not stored) uo that's translating the stuff in the dictionary and list values but not printing the word I entered that's not yet stored

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of your keys and values with a set comprehension then check for intersection :

```
>>> set_list={k[0] if isinstance(k,list) else k for it in Tuc.items() for k in it}
set(['me', 'love', 'i', 'ye', 'mine', 'o', 'sia', 'yeme', 'are', 'uo', 'yem', 'wau', 'my', 'you'])


if set_list.intersection(input_list):
     #do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following lambda for finding translations. If the word does not exist, it will return empty.

```
find_translation = lambda w: [(k, v) for k, v in Tuc.items() if w==k or w in v]
```

Usage = `find_translation(translation)`

```
>>> find_translation('i')
[('i', ['o'])]
```

*Edit:*

Modifying the result to convert whole string.
Since you mentioned that you want to convert list of words let's take the same lambda and use it for multiple words.

```
line = 'i me you rubbish'  # Only first three words will return something
# Let's change the lambda to either return something from Tuc or the same word back
find_translation = lambda w: ([v[0] for k, v in Tuc.items() if w==k or w in v] or [w])[0]

# Split the words and keep using find_transaction to either get a conversion or to return the same word
results_splits = [find_translation(part) for part in line.split()]
```

You will get the following results:

```
['o', 'ye', 'uo', 'rubbish']
```

You can put the string back together by joining `results_splits`

```
' '.join(results_splits)
```

And you get the translation back

> 'o ye uo rubbish'

Comment: Thank you for your help but this did not translate a full sentence it only gives me one word at a time and it displays both words as the result I need it to behave the same way it does with the difference of the word that's not stored returns itself

Comment: You could easily do a string replace or better yet, split the strings. I will update the answer

Comment: Awesome this is closer, however it didn't work both ways. It translates in only one direction and not tic to English and it has changed the behavior of the print direction, my program was printing the translation 1word per line because in some cases there's 2 Tuccin words for one English word to deal with homographs. So that's y I need translation to print word per line on translation

Comment: That is another issue.  I suggest you to close this question and open a new one with new issues.

Answer (score 0):

lets do this in simple way....create two dict for `Tuccin to English` and `English to Tuccin` translations.

```
In [28]: Tuc_1 = {k:Tuc[k][0] for k in Tuc} # this dict will help in translation from English to Tuccin

In [29]: Tuc_1
Out[29]: 
{'are': 'sia',
 'i': 'o',
 'love': 'wau',
 'me': 'ye',
 'mine': 'yeme',
 'my': 'yem',
 'you': 'uo'}

In [30]: Tuc_2 = {Tuc[k][0]:k for k in Tuc}  # this dict will help in translation from Tuccin to English 

In [31]: Tuc_2
Out[31]: 
{'o': 'i',
 'sia': 'are',
 'uo': 'you',
 'wau': 'love',
 'ye': 'me',
 'yem': 'my',
 'yeme': 'mine'}
```

example usage:

```
In [53]: translation = "I love You"

In [54]: input_list = translation.split()

In [55]: print " ".join(Tuc_1.get(x.lower()) for x in input_list if x.lower() in Tuc_1)
o wau uo

In [56]: print " ".join(Tuc_2.get(x.lower()) for x in input_list if x.lower() in Tuc_2)


In [57]: translation = "O wau uo"

In [58]: input_list = translation.split()

In [59]: print " ".join(Tuc_1.get(x.lower()) for x in input_list if x.lower() in Tuc_1)


In [60]: print " ".join(Tuc_2.get(x.lower()) for x in input_list if x.lower() in Tuc_2)
i love you
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this answer yet I'm having trouble following it